# Azure Powershell with storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I want to copy from Azure file share to blob and I am following below refs, and I wanted a incremental copy which is available in azcopy with not in Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy. And ofcourse Start-AzureStorageBlobIncrementalCopy wont do copy from file share to blob.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobincrementalcopy?view=azurermps-6.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobcopy?view=azurermps-6.8.1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobcopy?view=azurermps-6.8.1

I wrote small commands,

```
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'neverdelete' -StorageAccountKey 'XXX'
$Srcsh = Get-AzureStorageFile  -ShareName "filetest" -Context $StorageContext
$DestBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "client1" -Context $StorageContext
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcShare $Srcsh --DestContainer $DestBlob
```

But this throws an error below:

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare' required by parameter 'SrcShare'. Specified method
```

is not supported.
        At line:4 char:38
        + Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcShare $Srcsh --DestContainer $DestBlob
        +                                      ~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.StartAzureStorageBlobCopy

I dont know what I am doing wrong here and how do I script it so that it could be incremental.

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the 
`-SrcShare` parameter expects a `CloudFileShare` and you pass a list of `AzureStorageFile` / `AzureStorageDirectory`. Also your `-DestContainer` has two `--` and you are missing the context.

So you could e. g. iterate over your AzureStorageFiles and invoke the `Start-AzureStorabeBlobCopy` cmdlet for each of them:

```
$Srcsh | ForEach-Object {
    Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcShare ($Srcsh[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Share) -SrcFilePath $_.Name -DestContainer "client1" -Context $StorageContext
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I wanted a incremental sync, how I can perform that here. I will use azure automation account and keep this on schedule but everytime it will copy everything, can it be incremental?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to copy the files in the storage fileshare to storage container, you could try the command below.

```
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'StorageAccountName' -StorageAccountKey 'xxxxx'
$Srcsh = Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName "filesharename" -Context $StorageContext | Get-AzureStorageFile
$DestBlob = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Container "containername" -Context $StorageContext
foreach ($item in $Srcsh)
 {
    Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcFile $item  -DestContainer "DestContainername" -Context $StorageContext
 }
```

[image]

**My fileshare:**

[image]

**Result in the container:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy, I can confirm this working and now I understand why I was getting error. As I said,  I wanted a incremental sync, how I can perform that here. I will use azure automation account and keep this on schedule but everytime it will copy everything, can it be incremental?

Comment: @akshayvithalkar May be you are looking for : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobincrementalcopy?view=azurermps-6.8.1

Comment: Yeah, I already gone through it and it doesn't have parameter for fileshare.

Answer (score 0):

For Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy (Start-AzureStorageFileCopy), the cmdlets can only copy single File/Blob, can't copy a share/container, and the copy can't be resume if fail.

The incremental copy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/incremental-copy-blob) can only copy page blob snapshot, and currently File not support it. As you say AzCopy support it, what do you means about "incremental copy"?

If you want to copy all files in the root directory in a share, you can use following command. (Please note, Get-AzureStorageFile will only get the first level file/dir in a share or dir, it won't get the files in subdir.)

```
Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Context $StorageContext
| where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "CloudFile"} |Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy  -DestContainer $containerName -DestContext $StorageContext
-context $StorageContext
```

BTW, for any azure powershell problem, the formal way is to open an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues, and the proper team will follow up it.